# Uncaught TypeError: value.CommentTypes.join is not a function Angular

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angular, model-view-controller, typeerror

In angularjs I am using one method calling differently some time it gets value in array form and from another place it gets simple value not in array.

My method is:

```
function fillReviewObject() {
    angular.forEach(vm.surveyQuestion, function (value, key) {
        value.CommentTypes = value.CommentTypes.join(',');
    });
}
```

Value is Object I am taking value of "CommentType" from "Value' object. When I pass value in array format like,

```
CommentTypes Array(1)[2]
```

Commenttype array of length 1 having value '2'. It works fine in my code.

But when I pass Value object in such way,

```
CommentTypes = 2
```

Here it is not in array format and giving me type error.

Hopes for your suggestions!

Comment: You can use the `join` method only on arrays, otherwise, the function doesn't exist.
Try to check if the value is an array before using the `join` function,
maybe something like that:
`value.CommentTypes = Array.isArray(value.CommentTypes) ?  value.CommentTypes.join(',') : value.CommentTypes;`

Comment: Michal i am trying to do that but i was unable to solve it by checking is it array or not. So i made another method to move on that i was not willing to do :(

Comment: Why do you need to do another function? Can't you use `Array.isArray()` function?

Comment: Michael thanks it works !

Comment: Happy to hear that!. I added it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the join method only on arrays, otherwise, the function doesn't exist. Try to check if the value is an array before using the join function, maybe something like that: `value.CommentTypes = Array.isArray(value.CommentTypes) ? value.CommentTypes.join(',') : value.CommentTypes;`